# Elastic Beanstalk not scheduling jobs defined in cron.yaml

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-container-registry

I have a web and a worker environment on Elastic Beanstalk. I have a `cron.yaml` file that has a task that runs every hour. It was working fine in the beginning when I was deploying using `eb-cli`.

Then I decided to use AWS code pipeline to deploy code and that's when the cron job stopped working. The way it works is that the build stage of the pipeline creates a docker image and pushes it to my ECR repo. This image is then used (using `Dockerrun.aws.json`) in the next stage to run the app in both environments. But this approach does not schedule the tasks defined in `cron.yaml`.

I think with eb-cli, when elastic beanstalk unzips the archive uploaded to s3 for deployment by eb-cli, it finds that `cron.yaml` file and schedules the task. But with ECR, it's just the docker image and that cron.yaml is not available. If this is the case, how can I provide the `cron.yaml` file to elastic beanstalk when deploying from ECR repo?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue myself. All you need to do is add `cron.yaml` file to artifacts in your `buildspec.yml` file, like so:

```
artifacts:
    files:
      - Dockerrun.aws.json
      - cron.yaml
```